# Add a column to a list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists of the same dimension, now I try to add to "a", a fourth column at the end with the values of "b [2]".

```
a = [['3', 'LP', 132.5], 
 ['9', 'AP', -153.7], 
 ['18', 'DN', 11.7]]


b = [['3', 'AP', -103.3],
 ['9', 'CL', 131.8], 
 ['18', 'DN', -55.0]]
```

The result should be something like this:

```
result = [['3', 'LP', 132.5, -103.3], 
 ['9', 'AP', -153.7, 131.8], 
 ['18', 'DN', 11.7, -55.0]]
```

I have tried with the "append" method, and I almost get it, some suggestions?

Comment: Use append in a loop? Better yet: use a pandas dataframe since lists of lists are not conducive to columnar data.

Comment: What is it that you have tried and what output did you get, perhaps we can set you on the right path?

Comment: @JohnColeman, pandas might be overkill here.

Comment: Just zip, loop, append: `for m, n in zip(a, b): m.append(n[-1])` or list comprehension: `[[*a, b[-1]] for a, b in zip(a, b)]`

Comment: @Mark, the comprehension doesn't give the intended output.

Comment: @navneethc overkill perhaps, but why not plant a seed?

Comment: @navneethc are you sure about that? What output are you getting? Are you running it after the loop that modifies `a`? Those are meant as two alternative depending on whether or not you want to really mutate `a`.

Comment: Seed for confusion? Just kidding. ;-) The OP is having trouble working with lists and loops, I wouldn't burden them with an entirely new API at this point (and other unnecessary overheads), unless their use-case clearly warrants it.

Comment: @Mark, my apologies. I tried both your solutions one after the other, and I guess the mutability of lists messed things up when I ran the comprehension. (That's yet another thing that the OP must be wary of.)

Comment: Are they ordered or you have to check for equality of the first two elements?

Comment: It is not necessary to check, it is only the exercise of understanding how to add a column to an enlist of lists @Osman Mamun, I do not seek to operate with pandas for now.
Thank you very much everyone for your suggestions, an excellent day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [['3', 'LP', 132.5],
     ['9', 'AP', -153.7],
     ['18', 'DN', 11.7]]

b = [['3', 'AP', -103.3],
     ['9', 'CL', 131.8],
     ['18', 'DN', -55.0]]

result = []
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    result.append(v.copy())
    result[-1].append(b[i][2])

print(result) # [['3', 'LP', 132.5, -103.3], ['9', 'AP', -153.7, 131.8], ['18', 'DN', 11.7, -55.0]]
```

or with list comprehension:

```
result = [v.copy() + b[i][2:3] for i, v in enumerate(a)]
print(result) # [['3', 'LP', 132.5, -103.3], ['9', 'AP', -153.7, 131.8], ['18', 'DN', 11.7, -55.0]]
```